# How to generate deterministic batches of pseudo-random numbers in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, random, montecarlo

In python 3, `random.jumpahead` was deprecated (without much warning). How should this functionality be replaced?

I want to perform a large numerical experiment, aggregating many individual simulations:

1. Each simulation is pseudo-random (i.e. internally depends at several points on PRNG input, which should be different and somewhat-independent for each simulation).
2. My set of simulations is trivially-parallelisable, and so I want to be able to run separate simulations in different threads (or even as batch jobs on different machines at different times).
3. I want to use a deterministic PRNG and a fixed seed, to ensure my results are reproducible (and do not depend on how the experiment is parallelised).

Previously these criteria were met by each simulation using the same seed but a unique jumpahead (based from an id or enumeration of the simulations). Is there a recommended alternative or should I still try to implement this approach?

Answer (score 0):

The replacement to jumpahead is to use a separate `random.Random(seed)` for each simulation, where each simulation has its own seed. For example, each of your simulations can have a seed as follows:`seed = b"my_seed_%d" % seedNumber`, where `seedNumber` is different for each simulation. You can optionally send that seed to one of the hash functions provided in the `hashlib` library before passing it to `random.Random`.

---

UPDATE (Dec. 1):

If you're using NumPy (a Python library that is commonly seen in simulations), please note that in the meantime, NumPy 1.17 introduces a [new random number generation system](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/index.html); it uses so-called *bit generators*, such as PCG, and *random generators*, such as the new `numpy.Random.Generator`. It was the result of a [proposal to change the RNG policy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.rst). The NumPy documentation now has detailed information on [seeding RNGs in parallel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/parallel.html), and on [multithreading RNGs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/multithreading.html). I also have general information on seeding multiple processes (not NumPy-specific) in "[Seed Generation for Noncryptographic PRNGs](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Seed_Generation_for_Noncryptographic_PRNGs)."

Comment: Why is it necessary to scramble the number (before inputting it as seed), and what decides whether the scrambling method is sufficient?

Comment: Generally, each simulation's PRNG should use seeds that are _unrelated_ to each other, to reduce the risk of correlated random numbers between PRNGs (see, e.g., "[A Primer on Repeatable Random Numbers](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/01/07/a-primer-on-repeatable-random-numbers/)" and "[Wildly Varying Seeds](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Wildly_Varying_Seeds)"); this risk is greater if the seeds are sequentially assigned or linearly related.